# Slow root / mounting time

Tags: debian, arch-linux, mount, dmesg

By running `dmesg -t -d` on my Raspbian/Debian Jessie, I see that this is a bottleneck in my booting process:

```
[<    4.777880>] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): mounted filesystem with 
ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
```

Nearly 5 seconds to mount `/dev/mmcblk0p2` as root `/`, this is too long!

Ok it is a Raspberry Pi + a microSD card (so this could be a reason for slow mounting of `/`) but I did it with ArchLinux, and this mounting was not so long at all.

**How to prevent any filecheck on a read-only filesystem and have a faster root `/` mounting on boot?**

Comment: Do any previous log messages indicate that the file system in question is being checked (your question's wording makes it look like that's what you think is happening)?

Answer (score 0):

The line header `[<    4.777880>]` says that this messages happened about 5 seconds after the previous one, it doesn't say for sure that mounting, by itself, took this long; intermediate, unlogged events may have happened in between (as Celada mentioned in a comment).

On a recent boot of a Rasperry Pi, I see:

```
[    2.474306] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): couldn't mount as ext3 due to feature incompatibilities
[    2.485611] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): couldn't mount as ext2 due to feature incompatibilities

(More lines, none related to this device.)

[    3.329574] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): recovery complete
[    3.337860] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
```

That gives a mounting duration estimate of between 8ms and 864ms, depending on which message you assume indicates a mounting attempt, including apparently some time for recovery (presumably because the file system was marked dirty).

Comment: And even then, other events which didn't get logged might have occurred in between, so it doesn't really tell you how long it took to mount `/`.

Comment: Oh wait, the question uses `dmesg -t -d`... so these *are* deltas. My answer is completely wrong-headed.

Comment: Good catch. So *that's* what those angle brackets mean. I was wondering about those. I didn't know about that capability of `dmesg`.

Answer (score -1):

I’m not expert on Raspbian, but to answer this:

> How to prevent any filecheck on a read-only filesystem and have a faster root / mounting on boot?

you might want to have a look at the `fs_passno` field for the root filesystem line in the `/etc/fstab` file. IF present, it’s the sixth field of the line. It is usually `1` for root filesystem and `2` for other filesystems, meaning that the root filesystem will be checked first, before checking other filesystems. But if you set it to `0` it won’t be checked at all. (Unless enforced at some other level).

However, automatic checks of filesystems actually only happen every once in a while. You might want to consider shrinking your root filesystem, so that each mount will be quicker. Or else possibly change filesystem type at all: ext4 may be not the most apt for SD-cards.